How can I mock a super class and suppress calls to the actual super class constructor using mockito-inline?
I've seen some old questions about using the regular mockito mock maker. i.e. using the mockito-core dependency. I think this is not a duplicate because I'm using the new inline mock maker from mockito-inline instead. It supports constructor mocking so I think this should be possible now. I'm trying to remove the PowerMockito dependency I previously used so using PowerMockito isn't an option here. I'm trying to do this using JUnit 4 and Mockito 5.2.
I have a class in an android app BitmapCache extends LruCache<Uri, Bitmap>. The LruCache constructor throws a stub exception like all of the methods in android.os when not run on an android device. My the constructor for my class calls super(cache_size); inside its constructor. So I'm unable to instantiate an instance to test. I want to mock LruCache not BitmapCache and I want to suppress calls to the LruCache constructor. It seems Mockito's mockConstruction method still calls the mocked class constructor. Triggering the stub exception.
Is it possible using mockConstruction, mockConstructionWithAnswer, or some other feature using the new inline mock maker? I want to completely prevent the LruCache constructor from throwing the stub exception. Ideally preventing it from being called at all if possible or having it stubbed out with an empty function.
I obviously can't change the code in the parent class and this does need to extend LruCache. I think this would be a common issue in testing android code without spinning up a vm to run the tests on an android device.
I've tried setting defaultAnswer to all of the constant values including deep mocks and using mockConstructionWithAnswer, but they don't seem to be actually mocking the constructor, but every other method instead.
The exception is always thrown from the line inside the try block where I instantiate a BitmapCache object for testing.
I'm also not sure if this is an issue that LruCache is generic so my mocking looks like this to forcibly cast LruCache.class to Class<LruCache<Uri, Bitmap>>.
try (MockedConstruction<LruCache<Uri, Bitmap>> lruCache = 
    mockConstruction(
        (Class<LruCache<Uri, Bitmap>>) (Class<?>) LruCache.class))

I have also tried both of these approaches, but neither suppresses the call to the LruCache constructor.
With mockCache defined as
LruCache<Uri, Bitmap> mockCache =
    mock((Class<LruCache<Uri, Bitmap>>) (Class<?>) LruCache.class;

try (MockedConstruction<LruCache<Uri, Bitmap>> lruCache = 
    mockConstruction(
        (Class<LruCache<Uri, Bitmap>>) (Class<?>) LruCache.class,
        (mock, context)->{
            when(mock).thenReturn(mockCache);
})){

and
try (MockedConstruction<LruCache<Uri, Bitmap>> lruCache =
    mockConstructionWithAnswer(
        (Class<LruCache<Uri, Bitmap>>) (Class<?>) LruCache.class,
        (invocation) -> mockCache)) {

Update: I tried mocking the constructor for BitmapCache and that doesn't seem to be calling the LruCache constructor. I think the problem above is either mockConstruction doesn't work for super() calls or I'm not specifying the class or construction correctly in my calls to mockConstruction and mockConstructionWithAnswer.
I'm leaning towards the super() call isn't being intercepted. I tried mocking both classes as below and as soon the child class tries to call a "mocked" method on the parent class it actually calls the real method and throws the exception.
Bitmap bitmap1 = mock(Bitmap.class);
Bitmap bitmap2 = mock(Bitmap.class);
Uri uri1 = mock(Uri.class);
Uri uri2 = mock(Uri.class);

try (MockedConstruction<LruCache<Uri, Bitmap>> lruCache =
    mockConstruction(
        (Class<LruCache<Uri, Bitmap>>) (Class<?>) LruCache.class,
        (mock, context)->{
    // These four calls should prevent calls to the real LruCache
    // get or put methods from being called.
    doNothing().when(mock.put(any(Uri.class), any(Bitmap.class)));
    when(mock.get(uri1)).thenReturn(bitmap1);
    when(mock.get(uri2)).thenReturn(bitmap2);
    when(mock.get(any(Uri.class))).thenReturn(null);
})) {
    try (MockedConstruction<BitmapCache> bitmapCache =
        mockConstruction(BitmapCache.class, (mock, context)->{
        when(mock.put(any(Uri.class), any(Bitmap.class)))
            .thenCallRealMethod();
        when(mock.get(any(Uri.class)))
            .thenCallRealMethod();
    })) {
        BitmapLoader loader = mock(BitmapLoader.class);
        cache = new BitmapCache(cacheSize, loader);

        // This call calls the real BitmapCache method as expected,
        // but then that method calls the real LruCache.put method
        // instead of the mock.
        cache.put(uri1, bitmap1);
        cache.put(uri2, bitmap2);

        assertEquals(cache.get(uri1), bitmap1);
        assertEquals(cache.get(uri2), bitmap2);
    }
}


IDK about mocking subclass constructor, but have tried / considered using Robolectric which provides shadow implementations of Android classes?

Mocking the creation of the superclass when instantiating the child class works for me when using: mockito-inline v4.6.1 but not with v4.7.0.
And it still doesn't work with the latest Mockito: mockito-core v5.14.2
So the assert in the following TestNG unit test passes with v4.6.1 and fails with v4.7.0:
public class NewTest {

   @Test
   public void test() {

       try (MockedConstruction<Super> superConstructorMock = Mockito.mockConstruction(Super.class,
               (mock, context) -> {
                   Mockito.when(mock.getInt()).thenReturn(42);
               })) {

           Child c = new Child();
           Assert.assertEquals(c.getInt(), 42);
       }
   }

   class Super {

       int getInt() {
           return 0;
       }
   }

   class Child extends Super {}
}

I don't know if this is a bug in Mockito or if you are meant to do it differently.
